# Timeout Conception

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook-messenger

I develop a messenger chat box based on NodeJS and PostgreSQL.
I'm looking for the best way to develop that:

- A user must send a message to my bot at least every minutes, if it's not the case, the bot should send a message with 10 sec left. And if the user don't reply it must send another message chat ended
- If I restart my bot, I don't want to lose these timeout
- My NodeJS app can be scale minimum 2 instances balance randomaly.

That is the modelisation that I imagine:

- Save in database the last message dateTime
- Inside a transation with locked, run a cron every 10 seconds that check all user with lastmessage >= 50 seconds and < 60 and not kicked
- Inside a transation with locked, run a cron every 10 seconds that check all user with lastmessage >= 60 seconds and not kicked, kick this user

Do you have a better idea (can have 1 Millions user to  notify)?

Thank you

Comment: Nope, sounds great.

Comment: For best performance you can use redis + bull https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull